# Is there anyway t get the version history of Categories, keywords and structure groups

Tags: core-service

I m trying to get the versioning history of all the item in tridion using core service.

But since there is no versioning history in tridion for the categories, keywords, SG and folder I wonder how can I get the same using core service

(Right click any category in tridion, it will not have the versioning history option)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing available OOTB for categories and keywords as they are not treated as first class content citizens :(
Although depending upon your use case, you can capture the history for categories on every publish in app data as doing it on every save can be cumbersome. Once you capture the whole category on publish as an xml in app data (which includes keywords data as well for the category), then you can build functionality on top of it using GUI extension, like comparing different versions (based on your timestamp of capture in app data) or roll back (which will mean you have to update the category and the corresponding keywords using coreservice calls) from the data you gathered in app data. This is one of the viable way to achieve the history/versioning capability for categories and keywords.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, there is no version history stored for any of the organisational items (Folders, Structure Groups, Categories, Publications, etc), so you will not be able to get this, even if you use the Core Service.

I have seen an implementation in the past that used the Event System to store a copy of the Structure Group information every time it was saved (in a text file), but this has limited usefulness without being able to view / rollback to a previous version.

I try to get around this limitation (as far as possible) by using Components to store the configuration of these items. For example, storing Publication Settings in a separate Component, rather than in individual Publication Metadata fields. This also has the added benefit of being able to localise these Components (for other Publications), put these items through Workflow and controlling access to them through Security Permissions (rather than having to give `Publication Management` Rights).

Comment: To add comments to items, Chris Summers made the [Item Comment extension](https://github.com/TridionCommunity/tridion-powertools/blob/wiki/ItemCommenting.md) for the PowerTools. It was designed for pages and components, but can be configured for other items. The history is stored in Application Data and doesn't include the item name (the comment is manually entered), but this would be an alternative to the event system + text file approach.